# find php files in a folder recursively and pipe them into their folders with a changed file extension (*.mir say) after an operation on them

Tags: find, pipe

I have a piece of code that does most of what I required except that it puts all the generated files in the folder where the command is executed.

```
for f in `find /home/master/php/ -type f -name "*.php"` ; do php -w $f > `basename $f .php`.mir ; done
```

How can I modify this so that the .mir files are created in the folders of their  respective .php files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-execdir` to run in the right directory and avoid your whitespace-fragile loop, like this:

```
find /home/master/php/ -type f -name \*.php -execdir sh -c 'php -w "$0" > $(basename "$0").mir' '{}' \;
```

Comment: Works perfect, just as i wanted ! Would be grateful for some explanation of the code though. Thanks.